# Merge [emr] into [amazon-emr]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, there are tags for both [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr) (894 questions) and [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) (687 questions). They should be combined. There are too many to do so manually.

Comment: Do you really want them merged? If so, which one do you want to keep? If not, do you want them to be synonimised?

Comment: @DavidG wait, what? Is there a mechanism for "merging" tags that's not the same thing as synonymising them? I would've thought that synonymisation was clearly the correct thing to do, here, and that vy32 probably just didn't realise that it was possible.

Comment: I've retagged this as a `synonym-request`, on the assumption that vy32 simply didn't realise or remember that synonyms exist and could be used to handle this case. If that's a bad assumption, vy32, feel free to revert my retag.

Comment: Can you retag all questions at once, with a couple of clicks? Or with some small server-sided script?

Comment: Yes, there is a mechanism for merging tags that is different than synonymizing them. Merging is moderator-only. This seems like a good candidate for a merge *and* synonym.

Comment: @CodyGray ah. Link to any discussion about this power? I can't find anything on Google, and, given that the power exists, I don't really understand why it isn't used for every single synonym ever; what factors are normally considered to choose between plain old synonymisation and merging?

Comment: I'm sure there is a discussion somewhere, @mark, but it may be over on the global Meta. I am doing good to remember how this site works. I can't hope to remember *where* I learned everything—somewhere in reading Meta over the last 6ish years! Yes, the creation of a synonym should almost always merge the tags, but it doesn't. It's a serious design flaw, in my opinion. The whole tag synonym system is completely broken, but the Stack Overflow team has been completely ignoring pleas to fix it for the past 4 years or so. If you just create a synonym without merging, you get all kinds of brokenness.

Comment: Yes, I wanted the merged. It is confusing to type emr and be told that amazon-emr is also a tag.

Comment: I recommend amazon-emr as the official tag.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make *[emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr)* a synonym of *[amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr)*

The [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr) and [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) are used for the same thing (*Amazon Elastic MapReduce*). It's name, just **is** [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr). So the [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr)-questions should be merged and [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr) should be made a snyonym of [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) in the future.

Comment: Why are you against merging [emr] into [amazon-emr]?

Comment: I really think re-tagging and merging is the same thing...

Comment: It isn't. Retagging is a manual process that is *extremely* disruptive. Merging is automated.

Comment: Note : at the moment it doesn't seems to have things on topic on SO hat wqould imply a conflict in the acronym EMR.

Comment: Retagging is *opening each question, clicking edit and adding the tag*? ~900 times @CodyGray

Comment: Yes, basically. Except because it requires manually editing the question, when retagging, you should fix other problems with the question at the same time. Retagging is necessary when there are lots of low-quality questions with that tag, or when the tag has an ambiguous meaning and a direct merge is not appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray read the retag tag info: merging tags is just another flavor of retag requests

Comment: The same tag is appropriate. That doesn't mean they are the same activity.